# Вызвать системное время

Tags: android, время

Как можно получить системное время, чтобы исходя из его показаний создать сценарий работы приложения. Как то так:
Вызываем Значение времени = Х
Если Х позднее Константа, то реализуем 1 сценарий
Если Х не позднее Константа, то реализуем 2 сценарий
Если можно, с кодом...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Метод возвращает время с 1 января 1970 года в миллисекундах (если разделишь результат на 1000, то получишь Unix time). А дальше зависит от того в каком формате ты хочешь проводить сравнение. Если просто хочешь сравнить что Х позже чем время в системе, то просто указывай Х в Unix time и делай обычное сравнение.

```
if (x > System.currentTimeMillis())
{
 //todo
} else {
 //todo
}
```

Comment: Добавлю только, что делить надо на 1000

Comment: Точно, ошибся. Сейчас поправлю)